# Optimal Solution for function using Distributed Law

Tags: digital-logic

I was given the function:

\$ h = .' +  + .'. + . + '..'. \$

I was told to construct it in the most optimal way using only any size NOR gate by applying distributive law.

I proceeded as follows:
\$ h = (C+B'C)(C+D'F) + B'CD + BE + AB' \$

Which means I applied the distributive law on C and B'CD'F. Assuming \$x\$ to be \$C\$, \$y\$ to be \$B'C\$ and \$z\$ to be \$D'F\$ I got \$(x+yz = (x+y).(x+z))\$ and continued as follows for the remaining terms to come up with a final equation:
\$h = (AB' + BE + BD + B'C +C) . (C+D'F + BE +AB'+BD)\$

I then used de Morgan's law to come up with the NOR design. That is all I did. Can any other simplification be done?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Thank for the reply I proceeded as follows: 
h = (C+B'C)(C+D'F) + B'CD + BE + AB' which means i applied the distributive law on C and B'CD'F and assume x to be C y to be B'C and z to be D'F (x+yz = (x+y).(x+z)) and continued as follows for the remaining terms to come up with a final equation:
(AB' + BE + BD + B'C +C) . (C+D'F + BE +AB'+BD) now i used de Morgan's law to come up with the NOR design. That is all i did. If someone can see ant further simplification please tell me and thanks again

Comment: @cynthia Edit the question with whats in that comment and add formatting.

Comment: The title/question is just a load of squares and puntuation marks

Comment: @Andyaka is better now? I will rewrite the function here for your convinience: h=A.B' + C + B.C'.D + B.E + B'.C.D'.F

Comment: It's still the same cynthia - mabe it's a windows internet explorer thing?

Comment: @Andyaka, i'll edit it now.

Comment: @cynthia I have formatted your question, I hope I have not changed your meaning at all.

Comment: Thank you @Dean I really appreciate it. Now does anyone have any answer?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious simplification:

\$ C + B'CD'F = C \$

Which makes the function a lot smaller by eliminating a redundant term:

\$ h = A.B′+C+B.C′.D+B.E \$

The result \$ h \$ is not dependent on input \$ F\$.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Turbo J for the reply now can you help me use the distributive law to transform this function to POS. Thanks again!